# How to apply online learnig to Random Forest?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, online-learning

I have developed a random forest model for wind veliocity prediction with hyperparameter tuning, but i am getting continuous data. So i want to apply online leearning for random forest model. could you please suggets how to do with river library and scikit learn...?